# Android paging library - How to load data with paging library from certain position in the middle of the dataset?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-paging-library

I have an app that uses paging library to load contact data from room database. The query to load the data loads entries in asc/desc order and displays them in recycler view.
I want to implement sidebar with letters A-Z to jump to certain letter or to jump to a specefic record in the list (load around that record) and continue paging up/down from that record.
The same thing could be used for example in chat to start from first unread message but to allow scorll(load) older and newer messages.

I used recyclerView.scrollToPosition() with calculated position of first item I want to jump to, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it.